# Ruby - How to check string contains in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, extract

I want to extract a list which doesn't contain(not exact match) a word which I have given.
Example:

```
a = ["drop", "drop down", "forum", "drop down forum"]

b = ["drop", "drop down", "forum", "drop down forum", "data"]

Input string is str = "drop"

Output should be like: a = ["forum", "data"]
```

It is like a "LIKE" query in MySQL but I want to do it using ruby language. Please help to solve this.

Comment: Is there any reason your example data has two arrays? Why is the output of `a` `["forum", "data"]`? Must array `b` be combined with array `a` somehow?

Comment: Your title doesn't convey what you are trying to do. I think you want something like, "How to extract strings from an array that that do not contain certain words".  You don't need "Ruby" in the title because "ruby" is a tag (as it must be). You don't want rails as a tag because it is a pure-Ruby question. Moreover, the other tags won't help in searches, so I suggest that "ruby" be the only tag.

Answer (score 3):

Ref [reject!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21), Deletes every element of self for which the block evaluates to true.

```
list = ["drop", "drop down", "forum", "drop down forum"]
str = 'drop'
list.reject!{|item| item.include? str} # list = ["forum"]
```

Note :- include? is case sensitive for ex:- `'Drop down'.include? 'drop'` will return false.

For case insensitive we can do something like following

```
list.reject!{|item| item.downcase.include? str.downcase}
```

For multiple list you can do following

```
list_one = ["drop", "drop down", "forum", "drop down forum"]
list_two = ["drop", "drop down", "forum", "drop down forum", "data"]
(list_one + list_two).uniq.reject{|item| item.downcase.include? str.downcase} # ["forum", "data"]
```

Comment: It would help to use meaningful variable names, not `a` and `aa`. How about `list` and `item`?

Comment: Can't we extract it by comparing 2 arrays with given string(input) ? Updated the question.

Comment: What about `list = ["drop", "droplet", "gumdrops"]`? That's why @Sampat used a regex with word boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ["drop", "drop down", "forum", "drop down forum"]

list2 = ["drop", "drop down", "forum", "drop down forum", "data"]

result = (list1 | list2).reject{ |i| i.match(/\bdrop\b/i) }
=> ["forum", "data"]
```